# integral domain and irreducibility

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be UDF and a$\in R$. Then R/aR is integral domain if and only if $a$ is ireducible in R.

My Proof:

$R/aR$ is integral domain if and only if $aR$ is a prime ideal. Because $R$ is UDF so $R$ is PID. Then the principal ideal $aR$ is prime ideal if and only if $a$ is irreducible in $R$

Is it right?

And I like to know if it is true for doamin $R$ which is not Gaussian domain. Thanks.

Comment: What is a Gaussian domain? I'm not positive that's standard terminology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider: $\mathbb {Q}[x, y] $ is a Gaussian domain (or UFD), which is not PID.
Your statement holds for a quadratic number field.

But consider this:

$ aR $ prime ideal $\Leftrightarrow$ (For any $b,c\in R:$ $bc\in aR \Rightarrow b\in aR\vee c\in aR $)

$\Leftrightarrow$ (For any $b,c\in R:$ $\exists r\in R:bc= ar \Rightarrow \exists s\in R:b=as\vee \exists t\in R: c=at$).

$\Leftrightarrow$ (For any $b,c\in R:$ $a|bc \Rightarrow a|b\vee a|c$). $\Leftrightarrow $ $ a $ is prime $\Rightarrow $ $a$ is irreducible in $ R $.

The last implication holds for any integral domain. In a factorial ring (UFD), we have the equivalence, because in an UFD any irreducible element is prime (for a proof, please see e.g. http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mityab/teaching/m493f12/UFDs.pdf).

**Edit:** The last part is now a bit more explicit. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: The last equivalence isn't true in general - that's the definition of a prime element, not an irreducible element. The problem is to show that irreducible elements in $R$ are prime, which depends on what the OP means by Gaussian domain (I haven't seen this term used before).

Comment: @NoahOlander Gaussian domain=UFD

Comment: @mrbean123 you should put this in the statement of the question.

Comment: @DanielBernoulli how can I prove that my statment does not hold for $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 5]$

Comment: Let $a:=5$. Then $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is an integral domain, since it is a field, which we commonly note with $\mathbb{F}_5$. But $5$ is not an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}]$, since $5=\sqrt{5}\cdot\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{5}\notin(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{5}])^\ast$.